# Efficient way to find polygons with no neighbours, eg, detached houses

Tags: postgis, qgis-3

I have a map of buildings, I'm looking to identify only those buildings which are detached (no neighbours). I can run select by location touches in QGIS and invert this but it does not seem the most efficient way. Is there a PostGIS or QGIS method that will be quicker?

Edit; I'm testing this approach. https://geospatial.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2013/11/21/finding-islands-or-the-converse/

Answer (score 4):

You can now use [ST_ClusterDBSCAN](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) for this purpose, with a **minimum cluster size of 1** and a **distance parameter of 0**. This will cluster objects that are no more than a specified distance away from each other -- in this case, touching, as distance = 0 -- and, as it is a window function, you can easily get back the IDs of any geometries in each cluster as an array, using the array_agg function. Then all you need to do is select those clusters which only have one ID in the returned array that represents the ids per cluster, using the array_length function. Clusters of size one are your detached buildings.

Modifying the example query from the docs somewhat:

```
WITH clusters (cid, ids_in_cluster) AS ( 
 SELECT cid, array_agg(building_id) AS ids_in_cluster 
   FROM (
      SELECT 
          building_id, 
          ST_ClusterDBSCAN(geom, eps := 0, minpoints := 1) OVER () AS cid
        FROM some_table
       ) foo
  GROUP BY cid
)
SELECT cid, ids_in_cluster
  FROM clusters
 WHERE array_length(ids_in_cluster, 1) = 1;
```

This version of ST_ClusterDBSCAN, with distance 0, and minpoints 1, is essentially identical to [ST_ClusterIntersecting](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterIntersecting.html), which returns a set of geometries, which makes it more painful to infer which IDs/geometries are in each cluster. As DBSCAN is a window function, it allows you more flexibility with the results.

There is nothing wrong with the [approach in your question](https://geospatial.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2013/11/21/finding-islands-or-the-converse/). However, as it involves a spatial self-join, it is likely to be slower than the clustering approach.

Comment: Have you got any comments on this. There may be a syntax error, but I have run similar queries successfully on my own datasets.

Comment: Many thanks John, this is for a personal project which I will hopefully get back onto this weekend post deadline

Comment: No worries. I know how that feels :D